# Can't download Steam linux

Tags: steam

Whenever I click on the link to download Steam Linux, the link just takes me to a 403 page. I was wondering how to fix this as this did not happen when I downloaded Linux steam the last time I did this. I am on Chromebook, with an emulator for Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Which link are you talking about exactly? Try to download from the offical website: https://store.steampowered.com/about/

Comment: I was using the official site, it would just take me to a 403 every time I clicked on the link for the linux version. However it works now as i am making this.